# How to get the *real* date using Moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

So this has been on my mind for a long time - I was trying to "trick" my website and change my device's date. Unfortunately, this worked. I easily changed my laptop's date in the settings, entered the website and got the fake date. 
 
So my question is simple, how do I get the real date?

This was the code I used: (The PST real day is 17th of August), and I changed my device's date to the 20th of August:

```
moment().tz('America/Los_Angeles').toDate().format('D') //returns 20
```

Comment: You can't. You would have to get the date server side.

Comment: You would have to get it from a reliable source, like your server. Note that this is a fix for the user having the wrong date, not for them changing the date intentionally. They control the client-side JavaScript.

Comment: You could use something like https://timezonedb.com/references/get-time-zone or a similar network call to get the actual date if you don't want to trust the system time

Comment: What language is used with this extension may I ask?@sbrass

Comment: @icecoder it isn't an extension, it's a web service.  You can use any language you want.